# Android : fail to get the current location

Tags: android, position, location

For my app, I used the simple method `getLastKnownLocation` to get the current position of the user.

The problem is, of course, I dont't always have the true current position. So I found the method `OnLocationChanged` to be able to get the new position of the user.

I used this code :

```
locManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria crit = new Criteria();
crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
typeLoc = locManager.getBestProvider(crit, false);
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(typeLoc, 0, 0, this);
```

The problem is, my function OnLocationChanged is never called... why ?

Thanks

EDIT : permissions in XML :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

PS : i see there is googleplayservices which allows to get the current location, BUT, i want to know why this solution doesn't work. :(

Comment: I am assuming that you have the correct permissions set in android.xml, am I correct?

Comment: try to change minTime from 0 to more(1000 ms)

Comment: Maybe you forgot     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />

Comment: doesn't change anything..

Comment: Possible framework bug : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57707

Comment: mmhh, it's strange.... it will be incredible if google doesn't solve this issue from 1 year ago.